# Is there a difference between 'unknowingly' and 'unintentionally'?

Tags: meaning, differences, vocabulary

Sorry, it was unknowingly.
Sorry, it was unintentionally.

Comment: You might want to see if [ell.se] would be a better place to ask some of your questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. *Unknowingly* implies that the person didn't even realise they had done whatever it was. *Unintentionally* does not have that implication: they might or might not have realised they had done it, but either way they didn't intend to.

Incidentally, neither of those phrases is idiomatic: *Sorry, it was unintentional* is idiomatic, but the only similar form I can think of with *unknowingly* would be *Sorry, I did it unknowingly*, and even that sounds a bit stilted. More natural would be *Sorry, I didn't realise (I had done that)*.

Comment: And sometimes just, "Sorry, I didn't know."